# How to add AWS Java SDK to Scala / Play project

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt, aws-sdk

I'm playing around with Scala and Play, where I want to use the [AWS Java SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/).

I need to add the SDK to the project. And I know that I need to do that using the `plugins.sbt`.

**What I have tried**

```
resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"

addSbtPlugin("com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.11.46")
```

It's saying:

```
unresolved dependencies: Error:Unresolved dependencies:com.amazonaws#aws-java-sdk;1.11.46: not found`
```

As I am new to both Java, Scala and sbt I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

**The solution**

I was wrong about where to put the reference. It goes in `build.sbt` as it is not an sbt plugin, but rather a framework for the application to use.

Add the reference to `build.sbt` like this:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.11.46"
)
```

And you are good to go. You don't need a reference to any repositories, since the aws sdk is available in the default repos.

[See a list of available AWS Java SDK versions](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your problem is with SBT, the framework needs to be placed within `build.sbt` but you're trying to import it in as a plugin which it is not. Remove the plugin above, and put this line within your `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.11.46"
)
```

The have sbt build from there. If you are using Intelli J you can enable auto-import and have sbt automatically begin importing new or modified dependencies.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I just realized this aswell..And also I realized that the repository is also incorrect. I need to use the mvnrepository, as a resolver: resolvers += "MvnRepository" at "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk"

maybe you can update that in your answer, then I can take it as the answer

Comment: @CodeMonkey You don't need to specify maven repository since I believe sbt will by default try and look there.

Comment: seems you are right. I just needed to add the right reference to libraryDependencies. So basically it's a one-liner.